# Spring : files uploaded are deleted after server stops

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, file-upload, upload

I am using Spring Tool Suite on Windows XP, I upload images thru a form ([as described here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-mvc-multiple-file-upload-example)) :
- getting the server path thru `request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/")`
- and using the `transferTo` method

The files are correctly stored on : `C:\SpringInstall\vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.9.2.RELEASE\base-instance\wtpwebapps\myProject\img`

But as soon as **I stop or restart the server**, the files are deleted !
Ideally I'd like to keep files on my Spring workspace, which is `C:\SpringWorkSpace\myProject\` 
instead of `C:\SpringInstall\vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.9.2.RELEASE\base-instance\wtpwebapps\myProject\` 
How to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, this is not disturbing, since it appears only when developing. Once the application is deployed **on a real server**, the problem does not appear : the files remain.
I hope anyway that this issue will be usefull for some of you...